# How to change all children view text size in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

for ex:

```
    <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
        <Label text="From"/>
        <TextField fx:id="from"/>
    </HBox>
```

How to do following code to change Label and TextField text size:

```
<HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" textSize="48">
            <Label text="From"/>
            <TextField fx:id="from"/>
        </HBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use css.

Add a class to HBox, create a css file and link it to your fxml.

**file.fxml**

```
   <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" styleClass="parent" stylesheets="@style.css">
       <Label text="From"/>
       <TextField fx:id="from"/>
   </HBox>
```

**style.css**

```
   .parent {
       -fx-font-size: 20px;
   }
```

The "@" make the url path relative, in the example the style.css file is placed in the same folder of fxml.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the font size using CSS as inline style for the `HBox`, [see `style` Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#styleProperty). Font size is inherited, therefore all children use the specified font size:

```xml
<HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" style="-fx-font-size: 48;">
    <Label text="From"/>
    <TextField fx:id="from"/>
</HBox>
```

The correct property names for the CSS properties can be found in [the JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).